# Remove First and Last value from list in pandas dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas

my data frame looks like this.

[image: dataframe]

```
0   abc 2019-02-12 11:03:32 PM 12345
1   def 2019-02-14 11:04:33 PM 12345
2   blank
3   ghi 2019-02-14 11:05:34 PM 12345
```

Wanted output the below format.

```
0   2019-02-12 11:03:32 PM
1   2019-02-14 11:04:33 PM
2   
3   2019-02-13 11:05:36 PM
```

In short wanted to remove 1st and last values from each row and keep only date and time value.

Comment: The titel of your question mentions "list", but are these values indeed (Python) lists, or just strings with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

If need remove first and last values separated by spaces use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with indexing by `str[1:-1]` and then [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['A'] = df.A.str.split().str[1:-1].str.join(' ')
print (df)
                        A
0  2019-02-12 11:03:32 PM
1  2019-02-14 11:04:33 PM
2
3  2019-02-14 11:05:34 PM
```

Or:

```
df['A'] = df.A.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split()[1:-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.split().str[1:-1].str.join(" ")
```

which gives:

```
                        A
0  2019-02-12 11:03:32 PM
1  2019-02-14 11:04:33 PM
2
3  2019-02-14 11:05:34 PM
```

Comment: So same answer like me only changed `df.A` to `df['A']` ?

Comment: @jezrael Yes, it appears so.

Answer (score 0):

The first 1:3 slice index 0 and index 3 and index 1 and 2 would be printed

```
df = df.iloc[:, 1:2]
```